# Play background sound for a fixed custom interval?

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-process

I am developing a WP7 game which should notify the user with a sound once every minute as long as the game is running.

I would like this to happen even when the app is closed. I have tried some different schedulers (e.g. PeriodicTask) but they are all very restricted and do not allow such a small interval - the minimum is often 30 min.

I have tried the AudioPlayerAgent as well, which allows background audio playback, but I don't know how to run an AudioPlayerAgent which plays the sound once every minute?

Is it possible for me to have a background thread which keeps track of the game and plays a sound every minute?

Comment: That is not possible, because the background thread runs for 15 seconds once every half an hour. :(

Comment: This does sound like you're at risk of getting "less favourable" reviews, if you want the game to play sound/run battery down when not intentionally running. Maybe I'm just a miserable git that wouldn't allow a background agent for a game (in addition, background agents just plain aren't available come 7.1.1 for lower spec devices)

Answer (score 1):

You could play a track via the background audio agent that has a minute (or so) of silence between each sound and then loop it.

Is seems a hacky way to go and I'm not 100% certain of your exact requirements or why you really would want to do this anyway.